# Excel: IF all cells equals to one of two values, true, false

Tags: microsoft-excel, if

I need help with a formula in excel. The problem goes as this:
I have 5 cells that will have one of three values: Yes, No and N/A.
I tried creating a formula that shows “TRUE” if all these cells have the value either yes or n/a, else to show “false” but I can’t seem to figure it out.

What I tried goes something like this:

=IF(AND(OR(A1=“YES”, A1=“N/A), OR(B1=“YES”, B1=“N/A”), “TRUE”, “FALSE”))

It returns true even if there’s a “no” in those cells

Comment: Try `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:B1,"Yes")+COUNTIF(A1:B1,"N/A")=2,"True","False")`

Comment: If you have five cells, then why does your formula look at only 2 cells (A1 and B1)? Why doesn't it look at A1:E1?

Comment: Double-check the formula you've posted. There an error in the parentheses. Is it copy/paste from what you have in Excel? You have this `=IF(AND(OR(),OR(),"TRUE","FALSE"))` when I would expect `=IF(AND(OR(),OR()),"TRUE","FALSE")`. You're also missing a quote mark after the first `N/A`.

Comment: Further to @EngineerToast answer, I tested this and it works for me:  `=IF(AND(OR(A1="YES",A1="N/A"),OR(B1="YES",B1="N/A")),TRUE,FALSE)`  As shown in the question, you have a double-quote missing after the first N/A and some parenthesis problems.  Also, there are the decorative "directional" quotes in your posted question, remember that in excel formulas these must all be the straight, non-directional quotation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to simply return TRUE or FALSE, you can just make your formula show the TRUE or FALSE result of the condition without the IF().

So this performs the logic in a simple way, using the "+" operator to *mathematically* "OR" an array, but then uses the *logical* AND so that the result will be returned as TRUE or FALSE.

```
=AND((A1:B1="Yes")+(A1:B1="N/A"))
```

Further, your question suggests you have 5 values, where your example formula only covers A1 and B1.  The the formula above can be generalized to any number of columns, for instance:

```
=AND((A1:E1="Yes")+(A1:E1="N/A"))
```

The same logic works in a vertical list of values in column 1:

```
=AND((A1:A5="Yes")+(A1:A5="N/A"))
```

Comment: So what I need is as follows: I have five columns with different type of equipment handed over to an user. Some get equipment some don’t. When they leave the company, the it guys will need to fill an excel file with data if the users returned the equipment or not. If it’s returned or not applicable, another cell needs to show “true” otherwise “false”. So if it’s either yes or n/a, show true else show “false”

Comment: Understood.  `=AND((A1:B1="Yes")+(A1:B1="N/A"))' should produce that result in the fewest computational steps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have five values, you can just change the range and the total in the formula I suggested in my comment:

```
 =IF(COUNTIF(A1:E1,"Yes")+COUNTIF(A1:E1,"N/A")=5,"True","False")
```

Comment: I’m on mobile and just put two values, didn’t realize that I wrote 5 cells before. It was just as an understanding of the situation I’m facing

Answer (score 0):

### Dynamic Formula

*This solution uses a range of cells (rng) identified by name or A1/R1C1 reference.  It also uses a array (arr) of hard-coded values {"Yes","N/A"} to match against.*

---

1. Use SUM and COUNTIF functions to get a COUNT of all values in your range (rng) that match at least one value in your array (arr).
2. Use ROWS or COLUMNS function to determine the total number of rows or columns in your range (rng).
3. Use IF function to check if the result from step 1 (res1) is less than the result from step 2 (res2) meaning at least one cell did not match a value in your array.  You equate this to "FALSE" (F).

```
     +---------------+
 1.  | Count Matches |  =SUM(COUNTIF(rng,{arr}))
     +---------------+

     +---------------+
 2.  | Count Checked |  =ROWS(rng)        // alternatively: =COLUMNS(rng)
     +---------------+

     +---------------+
 3.  | Count Checked |  =IF(res1<res2,"F","T")
     +---------------+

     +---------------+
 4.  | Combine Them  |  =IF(SUM(COUNTIF(rng,{arr}))<ROWS(rng),"F","T") 
     +---------------+
```

**Plugging In Sample Data** *(5 Columns in Row 1)*

```
  =IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A1:E1,{"Yes","N/A"}))<COLUMNS(A1:E1),"False","True")
```

---

### Extra Option

In the solution, the array of values to check against (arr) is is hard-coded in the formula {"Yes","N/A"}.

Alternatively, you could instead point to a range of cells identified by name or A1/R1C1 reference (arrRng).

In order for that to work, you would need to remove the array braces "{ }" in the formula.

This is obviously not necessary in this case but might be if you reuse in the future for another case.

```
 =IF(SUM(COUNTIF(rng,arrRng)<ROWS(rng),"F","T")   // arrRng vs {arr}
```